# How do I accomplish the following merge using yq?

Tags: yq

I'm trying to take everything from two.yaml and merge it into one.yaml under top-level. Is this possible with yq?

**one.yaml**

```
top-level:
  a:
    create: false
  b:
    one: "one"
    two: "two"
```

**two.yaml**

```
application:
  executable: test
a:
  name: test
b:
  three: "three"
  four: "four"
c:
  enabled: true
```

**expected result**

```
top-level:
  application:
    executable: test
  a:
    create: false
    name: test
  b:
    one: "one"
    two: "two"
    three: "three"
    four: "four"
  c:
    enabled: true
```

I tried researching a solution and played around with loading the files and using `ireduce` with no luck.

Example:
`yq 'load("one.yaml") as $d1| load("two.yaml") as $d2 |  ($d1 | keys | .[]) as $i ireduce($d2;  .top-level[$i] = .top-level[$i] // $d2.top-level[$i])' one.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
yq eval-all 'select(fi == 0).top-level * {"application": select(fi == 1).application, "a": select(fi == 1).a, "b": select(fi == 1).b, "c": select(fi == 1).c}' one.yaml two.yaml > merged.yaml
```

The eval-all function evaluates an expression against all the documents in all input files. select(fi == 0).top-level selects the top-level map from the first file (indexes start at 0). The * operator merges the subsequent map into the top-level map.

This subsequent map is created by taking each map from two.yaml and adding it to a new map. The new map's keys are the same as in two.yaml, and the values are selected using select(fi == 1)., where  is the key from two.yaml.

The result is written to merged.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge and update at once using `*=`:

```bash
yq '.top-level *= load("two.yaml")' one.yaml
```

```yaml
top-level:
  a:
    create: false
    name: test
  b:
    one: "one"
    two: "two"
    three: "three"
    four: "four"
  application:
    executable: test
  c:
    enabled: true
```

Also see the section on how to [merge two files together](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-two-files-together) in the manual.